# Vector space proof confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S=\{\alpha(1,1,1)+\beta(1,2,1): \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}\}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that set $S$ (with the usual addition operation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space.

I know how in general to prove that something is a vector space. But with this example, I am not sure how $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ look like? Is it that $\mathbf{u}=\alpha_1(1,1,1)+\beta_1(1,2,1)$ and $\mathbf{v}=\alpha_2(1,1,1)+\beta_2(1,2,1)$?

Comment: Right. Then check as usual that sum has the same form and that $\lambda \cdot v$ has this form too for any scalar $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The vectors in $S$ look exactly how you wrote them, and you can use that to show that $S$ is a vector space.
Alternatively, you can show that $S=\mathrm{Span}\{(1,1,1),(1,2,1)\}$ and then $S$ is a vector space by the basic property: $\mathrm{Span}(K)$ is a vector space for any subset $K$ of a vector space $V$.

Comment: By definition? I don't think so, unless you are defining the span to be the smallest vector space containing; if instead you define the span as the set of all linear combinations, you still have to prove that that's a vector space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I guess you are absolutely right. What I meant is that a general methodology for proving that something is a vector space is using "$\mathrm{Span}(\text{some set of vectors})$ is a vector space". This is of course a statement that one proves, not a definition.